# Question regarding simple harmonic motion?

Tags: calculus, applications

[image]

Hi guys,
I was just wondering what the answers are for this question, as it says it's B, and I'm only getting C as an answer (attempted multiple times). Could anyone please just clarify what the answer is, and if it **is** B, any explanation would be great, but I'm not convinced that it is the answer.

I found the amplitude and used the condition $x=0, v=4$ to find my answer

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period of the function $f(x)=\sin(ax)$ is given by $$2\pi /|a|.$$ From this we can rule out answer $A$ since $a$ must be equal to $2$. Now, if the velocity has a maximum value of $4$ then the amplitude of the *derivative* of the function $x(t)$ must be equal to $4$. The only function that satisfies this answer $C$. To prove, let $x(t)=2\cos(2t)$, therefore $$x'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=2\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\cos(2t)=-4\sin(2t).$$

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, didn't think it was possible for the answer to be B :P

Comment: You're welcome.